# 1 function correctly firing on IOS, 1 not firing

Tags: javascript, html, ios, navigation

I am struggling with mobile navigation using JS and JQuery to scroll.

I have extracted the following scripts from my site and added a brief summary of the HMTL elements.

On Desktop (chrome 60.0.3112.113) the Nav works ok and both scripts (scroll() and islandGo() - which utilises scroll()) correctly fire.

When using IOS to debug, only the islandGo() fires correctly - with the standalone scroll() not working.

Is it to do with the second being within a function 'wrapper'?

If so, then it seems relatively simple to solve, I'm just wondering if I am missing some fundamentals.

Thanks in advance

```js
function scroll(cli) {
    "use strict";
    var target = '#'.concat(cli);
    console.log(target);
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(target).position().top - 90}, 500);
}

function island(d) {
    "use strict";
    document.cookie = "location=" + d + ";path=/;expires=1";
}

function islandGo(z) {
    "use strict";
    island(z);
    scroll('mainblock');
    console.log("Location = " + z);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="navLink-l1" title="Island" class="location-content" onmouseup="javascript:islandGo('island')" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; z-index: 5; text-decoration: none; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  <div id="content-l1-div" class="position: relative; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <span>
      ISLAND
    </span>
  </div>
</a>

<a id="navLink-l2" title="OTHER" class="body-content" onmouseup="javascript:scroll('other-content')" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; z-index: 5; text-decoration: none; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  <div id="content-l1-div" class="position: relative; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <span>
      OTHER
    </span>
  </div>
</a>

<div id="page-spacer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: transparent;"></div>

<div id="mainblock" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 500px; background: blue; padding: 200px;">
  CONTENT
</div>

<div id="page-spacer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: transparent;"></div>

<div id="other-content" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 500px; background: blue; padding: 200px;">
  !! OTHER CONTENT
</div>
```

Comment: What does not work? Does the function get called? Does the console fire, is the element found.... etc

Comment: The function gets called, I'm wondering if it is something to do with the treatment of the string for the element ID

Comment: Does it find the element? Does it find the position correctly?

Comment: That's my thought, the part I can't get my head around is why one instance finds "mainblock" and the "other" is not found. It's possible that it's the element, although there are several instances of scroll() on the page and none of them Fire correctly. Whereas, all instances of islandGo() work fine